# Do i have to close a file before opening it in another mode?

Tags: c, file-io

As in the title - do i have to call fclose() before opening the same file in another mode?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  // do some reading

  // do i have to call fclose() here?

  file = fopen("test.txt", "w");
  // do some writing

  fclose(file);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is something you can try by doing.  Is `file` `NULL` in the second call?

Comment: the file pointer isnt NULL even if i call fclose() two times

Comment: `fclose` doesn't set `file` to `NULL`.  That's something you'd have to do yourself.  Similar to `free` doesn't set `ptr` to `NULL`.

Comment: Im not really concerned about the file pointer being not NULL, im more concerned about having the file leaked if i don't call fclose() before opening it again

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer... but: it *feels* right to close, better safe than sorry, one *extra* `fclose()` will not impact the program, bla bla bla, so **yes, do `fclose(file);` before opening in a different mode**. Otherwise, if you're doing it millions of times in a loop, consider `fopen("blablabla", "r+")` ... and move that functionality out of the loop.

Comment: Yes, r+ is really useful, but it does not create a new file if it doesn't exist sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Close after file jobs's  done is a good  habbit.
Process has  limited  handle,  so if you open many times,  without  close,  you  can  face  fopen  fail.